# Change WooCommerce only 2 left in stock text

Tags: woocommerce, stock

WooCommerce stock status help needed!

I have opted to show stock availability only when 2 or less are in stock.

(https://i.stack.imgur.com/maZQc.png)

Please be so kind to help me change the text from "only 2 left in stock" to "Hurry! Only 2 left in stock"

:/

Thank you in advance!